# What is the package `unstructured` used for in k8s.io /apimachinery?

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I could not understand what the package can do, the offical doc show nothing about `unstructured`. What the package used for ? Is it used for converting map[string]interface{} to K8S Obj ?

https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/unstructured

Comment: I think this should be asked on github.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `unstructured` provides an interface to kubernetes objects, when you don't know object type upfront, i.e. [dynamic](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/dynamic/interface.go) package in client-go uses it extensively

Answer (score 2):

As @kseniia-churiumova suggested it is used when you don't know the object type. Here is the use case to understand it better. Let us say your organisation has a policy that all Kubernetes object must have annotation "owner" with value pointing to email ID of a person or group. You have tasked with finding all the resources that violates this policy.

You can have a configuration file that has list of `GroupVersionKind` and use unstructured to query them. If a new type needs a check you can add to configuration without changing the code.

**Note:** This is just an example. In production you will have to use something like Gatekeeper that implements OPA specification to enforce policies.